# What is the advantage of copy_if_different over copy in CMake?

Tags: cmake

The CMake Command-Line Tools support a `copy` and a `copy_if_different`:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.26/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-E-arg-copy

The `copy_if_different` is almost always slower because it must read the source and the target file, compare them and then copy if the contents have not been equal.

On the other hand `copy` will always just execute the copy part. This is slower then skipping the copy based on the files timestamps. Nevertheless it is much faster then `copy_if_different`.

When should I use `copy` and when `copy_if_different`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the timestamp of the copied file is relevant, then use `copy_if_different`, otherwise use `copy`.

E.g. if what you're copying is mentioned in the `DEPENDS` argument of another custom command then copying these files unconditionally triggers a re-build of that other custom command as well, as the timestamp of the copy will be newer. That will not happen with `copy_if_different` as the target file will not be updated if there were no changes.

Comment: Side note: I've made a [feature request for `copy_if_newer`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/24923).